# How to Convert a view into a Pane or Panel in Red

Tags: red

So I have a view that is currently working and looking like I want. What I would like to do take the content it contains wrap it inside a variable and put it inside of a tab-panel. To do this, I believe I need to convert it to a panel or some such. But I am not really sure how.

Here is the view,

```
        Red [ Title: "Editor"  needs: 'view]

        s: 110x25
        ts: 50x50

        view [size 800x800 title "Red Edit"

        drop-down s "Debug" data ["Debug" "Release"] 
        drop-down s "Windows" data ["Windows" "MacOSX" "Linux" "BSD" ] 
        button s "Compile" []  across
        button s  "Run" []


         return
            a: area 700x700 black
        ]
```

Here is the tab-panel

```
       view [backdrop brown
            title "Red Edit"
            tab-panel 820x820 [
                  "File1" []

                              ]
        ]
```

It would go inside of the first tab named "File1".
My attempts thus far have given me a compiler error telling me that the panel I am trying to create has no value.

Also, tips on syntax and coding style would be appreciated too since I am still learning red.

**Update**: here is how I would like to combine them :

```
    Red [ Title: "Editor"  needs: 'view]
    s: 110x25
    ts: 50x50

    p: [size 800x800 title "Red Edit"

    drop-down s "Debug" data ["Debug" "Release"] 
    drop-down s "Windows" data ["Windows" "MacOSX" "Linux" "BSD" ] 
    button s "Compile" []  across
    button s  "Run" []


     return
        a: area 700x700 black
    ]



    view [backdrop brown
    title "Red Edit"

    tab-panel 820x820 [
        "File1" [text "hello" p]

                                  ]
    ]
```

If I do this, p never gets displayed.

Comment: Use `layout` instead of `view` and `??` it. I think you are confusing it as something else. For more details, check out the rebol2 view docs

Comment: Yes, I am aware of layout, I am just not sure of the mechanics of it. I have a working and a non-working example, but I can't figure out what is different.

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: Do you understand what I am trying to do in general?  I would like to put the content representing the buttons and dropdowns and area inside of the tab-panel. Is that something you can show me how to do?

Comment: The Red documentation on Tab-panel looks like this : 7.3. tab-panel
Syntax
tab-panel <options> [<name> <body>...]
<options> : optional list of settings for the panel.
<name> : a tab's title (string!).
<body> : a tab's content as VID description (block!).
VID Dialect
48
Description
Constructs a tab-panel panel inside the current container. The spec block must contain a pair of name and content
description for each tab. Each tab’s content body is a new child panel face, acting as any other panels.

Comment: `What I would like to do take the content it contains wrap it inside a variable and put it inside of a tab-panel` This is not clear enough to make an answer. Do you really need to do that dynamically at run-time? If not, why don't you just copy/paste your VID code for your "view" inside the block after `"File1"`?

Comment: I intend to be able to dynamically add and remove tabs at runtime. This content will be in every tab.

Comment: The overwhelming majority of the documentation on how to use red focues on the apis View, and Vid,and not syntax or primitives which tends to be where I am struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was going to make a guess about your intentions, I think your real question is:

## How can I compose and glue GUI stuff together?

There are several ways to do this, but the first thing you should ask is:

### Do I need to?

As @dockimbel says if it isn't dynamic, you can simply have it after `tab-panel` word inside the dialect block `[]`, and this is idiomatic:

```
tab-panel [<rest of gui here>]
```

### Method 1: Compose into the dialect with a *block*

This is the next simplest way, using your code:

```
Red [ Title: "Editor"  needs: 'view]

s: 80x25
ts: 50x50

cnt-object: layout cnt-view-dialect-blk: [
    ;size 80x80 title "Red Edit"
    drop-down s "Debug" data ["Debug" "Release"] 
    drop-down s "Windows" data ["Windows" "MacOSX" "Linux" "BSD" ] 
    button s "Compile" []

    ;across
    button s  "Run" []

    return
    a: area 350x150 black
]

; view cnt-object

pnl-object: layout pnl-view-dialect-blk: compose/deep [
    title "Red Edit"
    tab-panel 400x200 [
        "File1" [(cnt-view-dialect-blk)]
    ]
]

view pnl-object
```

### Method 2: Use the view `face!` *object*

This requires a steeper learning curve, but makes everything much easier when you learn it, and is probably more efficient too! If you read the documentation for [`face!`](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_face_object):

```
button: make face! [type: 'button]
```

Then look back at what I've named as `-object` in the code above, you realize they are conceptually the same thing. That is, an `object!` created with `make`.

If you're doing this way, one of the most useful things is `/pane` and `/parent` to move up and down the hierarchy

### Further considerations

View is not a "thing" as it appears on the surface. It may refer to the VID *dialect* (what you have in *[blocks]*), or `view` *function* which is used to display things in the view engine. The actual things are `face!` objects, created manually with `make` or by the `layout` function.

I've labelled `-view-dialect-blk`, written in the actual view dialect, which is conceptually different from the actual objects. If you inspect all that I've labelled with `??`, I think you'd be a few steps closer to understanding how everything works under the hood ;-)

It's also good to read up on [rebol2 view concepts](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/Concise%20Guides/Concise%20Rebol-View.html) and the [official documentation](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rebol%20view%20docs%20site%3Arebol.com&t=ffsb&ia=web) until red's catches up with it. Though slightly different, the concepts are the same

Comment: The  "File1" [(cnt-view-dialect-blk)]  that syntax is what I needed :)

Comment: Actually, no. I see that what you have given me works, but I still don't understand it.

Comment: What does compose/deep do?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett `compose` is a general purpose function in rebol, the best advice I can give you is read more documentation, and come on the [gitter](https://gitter.im/red/help) chat. (also, keep posting questions! :D)

Comment: You can count on the questions part ;)